# How could you obtain a 2D heat map mean of a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I would like to output 2D scientific figures for a 3D-point cloud that I am currently working with. The data consists of one 3D numpy array defining the coordinates in three dimensions (x, y and z) and another numpy array that consists of the concentration (or intensity) at every point. I would like to average the results over the z-direction, so that I can e.g. plot the mean concentration in a 2D (x,y) heat map. How would I go about averaging these results?

The data set looks like:
'coordinates': [[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ...,  [xn, yn, zn]]
'concentration': [c1, c2, ... cn]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried till now ?

Comment: You say you're going to average `z` to get the concentration, but you already have the concentration in the other array.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has not much to do with heat map, it is a question of reshaping data.
From you question, I understand that each point in the (x,y) plane has several corresponding z coordinates.
You need to compute your intensities (concentration means) in a 2D-array according to the different values of x and y.
To do this it takes 4 steps :
- identify the points of coordinates (x,y) with `==`
- convert it into a 1-D array with `numpy.prod` (translate it as "and")
- extract the corresponding concentrations `numpy.extract`
- compute mean value with `numpy.mean`
You can not escape iteration over the points.

I tried it with random values and it seems to work :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = 5000
points = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, (l,3))
plane_points = points[:, 0:2]
cc = np.random.random(l)
intensity = np.zeros((11,11))
grid = np.arange(11)

for i in grid :
    for j in grid :
        intensity[i, j] = np.mean( np.extract( np.prod( plane_points == [i,j], axis=1 ), cc) )


x_mesh,y_mesh = np.meshgrid(grid, grid)
plt.pcolormesh(x_mesh,y_mesh, intensity)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that this is indeed one way to approach it. I am sorry that I did not update this tread, but I found another way to plot it in a 'heat map' (see my edited post).

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved the problem was as follows. I figured that I do not need to care about the z-coordinate of the different points, as the 2D 'heat map' will average the values in every grid. I choose to use hexbin, as this function can better divide the entire space than a square heatmap.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm

x = array['coordinates'][0]
y = array['coordinates'][1]
c = array2['concentration']

plt.hexbin(x, y, C=c, cmap=cm.jet, gridsize=15,bins=None)
cb = plt.colobar()
plt.xlabel('x coordinates')
plt.ylabel('y coordinates')
plt.show()
```